# How to get use of tmpfs spare space on my Fedora virtual box?

Tags: linux, fedora, disk-space

I am running out of disk space. How can I make the **tmpfs** space usable?

```
df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   11G   10G   99M 100% /
devtmpfs                 4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    4.9G  2.6M  4.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    4.9G  680K  4.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    4.9G  1.3M  4.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M   90M  359M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   45G   35G  7.8G  82% /home
```

Comment: symlink some stuff you don't really need into `/tmp`? Be aware though that `tmpfs` is backed by memory, so its contents will be gone as soon as you reboot (or your machine crashes).

Comment: probbably a better idea to move/symlink some stuff into `/home` instead, also a lot of free space and will not disappear on next boot. Or shrink your `/home` partition and grow `/` instead.